# Non-simultaneous memory use from multiple threads & caching

Tags: c, multithreading, compiler-optimization, cpu-cache

I have a main thread that maintains an array of pointers to some data. At some point, it spawns a new thread and passes one of the pointers to it. After that moment it does not use that pointer. The thread does its job (possibly modifies the pointed data) and uses a pipe to tell the main thread that it can use that pointer again.

main thread:

```
struct connection *connections[4];
// initialize connections
while (1)
{
    // ...

    if (...)
    {
        pipe(p);
        connection->control = p[1];

        pthread_create(&thread_id, 0, &handler, connections[i]);
        pthread_detach(thread_id);

        // ...
    }

    // ...

    if (pipe_data_available[i])
    {
        // do something with connections[i]
    }

    // ...
}
```

other thread:

```
void *handler(void *arg)
{
    struct connection *connection = arg;

    // do something with connection

    write(connection->control, data, data_size);

    return 0;
}
```

The two threads access the same memory but never at the same time (the main thread does not touch the pointer when the spawned thread uses it).

I have concerns that the main thread may not see the modifications of connections[i] done by handler (due to cache). Can this happen and, if yes, what is the best way to make sure the main thread sees the modifications?

Comment: This kind of inter-thread comms, (ie passing around pointers from some pool), is quite common and absolutely fine, at least on Intel hardware.  It's more often done by means of a loop in the thread and blocking queues for the actual comms and also for storing the pooled pointers, but what you are doing seem OK to me, (even if incurring avoidable continual thread creation).

Answer (score 0):

No, there will not be any cache issue between threads. This is managed and cannot happen.

The mechanism is called cache coherence. Even if both threads are running on different cores with different caches, the cache is properly invalidated between cores.

The only possible problem arises when both threads access the memory at the same time. It seems from you question that you avoid this problem by using "pipes", I'm not familiar with pipes but this is more often done with API object called "mutexes".

http://mortoray.com/2010/11/18/cpu-memory-why-do-i-need-a-mutex/

Comment: This is totally wrong in the general case.  Cache coherence is very definitely an issue.

Comment: Yeah.  Empirically, it works fine on Intel hardware.

Comment: I use pipes because I have multiple threads and I can poll() to see when each one of them finishes.

Comment: Cache coherence is only an issue regarding performances, not thread safety, at least on the usual platforms/hardware. Do you have an example of platform where the above situation could cause a not-up-to-date cache read?

Comment: @martinkunev : you do not need to wait threads to finish, you just need to wait until they release the mutex which flags that they are currently writing to memory. Your approach is fine but the mutex one is just more the classical way to do this (thus more understandable by a majority of people)

Comment: @galinette - I meant that I wait for the thread to finish its job (so that I can do whatever is necessary after). In my case I have a pool of file descriptors (listening sockets, other sockets, pipes, etc.) and I perform actions with them when an event arrives (currently using poll()). I can not achieve that with mutexes.

Comment: @martinkunev : OK, understood. Adding an extra mutex for guarding the shared memory area would be a good idea, though, for safety and readability of your guarding mechanisms. Avoiding the mutex should only be done when it may be proved that it reduces performances significantly and critically.

Answer (score 0):

In practice this will work on most architectures you're likely to run this code on. If you want to be standards compliant read: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_11.

That says that you can't be guaranteed memory to be synchronized unless you call one of the pthread locking functions and a few other functions. You can't be guaranteed that the architecture you're running on is cache coherent even though (almost?) everything modern is.